# Decomposition of a matrix into two non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Assume we're trying to find $A\in [-1,1]^{n\times d}, B\in [-1,1]^{m\times d}$, from an observed matrix $C\in [-d,d]^{n\times m}$, where $C=AB^T$.

The goal is to return $\widehat A, \widehat B$ such that $\widehat A \widehat B\approx C $.

If we had $n=m$, then this is a simple SVD decomposition (and deletion of the $n-d$ smallest singular values, if there's noise).

**How can we address the case where the dimensions aren't the same?**

Is it possble to efficiently find $\widehat A, \widehat B$ such that $\widehat A \widehat B= C $ (assuming such $A,B$ exist)?

If not, can we find $$minarg_{\widehat A, \widehat B}||C-\widehat A \widehat B||_F$$?

this seems doable by writing all $mn$ constraints and running least squares, but I'm wondering if it has a nice close form.

Are $\widehat A, \widehat B$ unique (up to rotation/scaling/permutation)?

Comment: Why can't you use SVD in the case when $m\neq n$? it is well defined for any combination of dimensions. Just take the first $d$ singular values and set the others to zero.

Comment: @PavelJiranek - I didn't write the domain correctly.
The entries in A and B should be in $[-1,1]$. 
Do you see how to use the SVD for this task? Thanks!

Comment: Now this is something completely different, which, by the way, most likely invalidates your comment about the SVD. Also, I guess it could be much easier for you to start with minimizing the Frobenius norm instead of the spectral one.

Comment: I suggest you to read [this article by Joel Tropp](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061), or [this short tutorial](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~jtropp/slides/Tro14-Finding-Structure-ICML.pdf), he explain several randomized scheme to obtain such a matrix decomposition.